# Xamarin Azure Blob Storage Not Returning/Authorizing

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-storage

I have tried all of the Xamarin Storage snippets I could find but Azure never returns anything or stores anything.  It  often does not even throw any exceptions, just ignores much of the code it seems.

I am down to these:

```
 public async Task<string> TestStorage()
 {
    CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(Settings.StorageContainerUrl), new StorageCredentials(Settings.StorageAccountName, Settings.StorageAccountKey));
    //CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("mytest2");
    //await blob.UploadTextAsync("This is newly uploaded data");
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("mytest");
    string data = await blob.DownloadTextAsync();
    return data;
}
```

If I give it an incorrect StorageContainerUrl or a StorageAccountName then Azure throws an error.  So far so good, it must be connecting and validating that information.  I've also confirmed that if I use a Blob name that doesn't exist, then Azure Storage throws StorageException: The specified blob does not exist.

However, if I give it a bad StorageAccountKey then no exception is thrown.

Furthermore, the DownloadTextAsync command returns nothing for an existing blob -- in fact it never returns and string data is never set.  Eventually an exception is thrown:

```
[0:] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Security.Cryptography.IncrementalHash.CreateHash (System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Security.Cryptography/IncrementalHash.cs:39 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.MD5Wrapper..ctor () [0x0001c] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\MD5Wrapper.cs:63 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StreamExtensions+<WriteToAsync>d__1`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00112] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\StreamExtensions.cs:269 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1[T].MoveNext () [0x009c6] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:215 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1[T].MoveNext () [0x01034] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:311 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob+<>c__DisplayClass68_0+<<DownloadRangeToStreamAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00095] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:343 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob+<>c__DisplayClass41_0+<<DownloadTextAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00061] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:594 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at QwikQuestion.Services.StorageDataService+<TestStorage>d__17.MoveNext () [0x00095] in C:\Users\alex\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\QwikQuestion\QwikQuestion\QwikQuestion\Services\StorageDataService.cs:56 
Request Information
RequestID:39730ffc-0001-00ed-45ed-69f892000000
RequestDate:Sun, 08 Jan 2017 20:27:34 GMT
StatusMessage:PartialContent
[0:] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Security.Cryptography.IncrementalHash.CreateHash (System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Security.Cryptography/IncrementalHash.cs:39 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.MD5Wrapper..ctor () [0x0001c] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\MD5Wrapper.cs:63 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StreamExtensions+<WriteToAsync>d__1`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00112] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\StreamExtensions.cs:269 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1[T].MoveNext () [0x009c6] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:215 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1[T].MoveNext () [0x01034] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:311 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob+<>c__DisplayClass68_0+<<DownloadRangeToStreamAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00095] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:343 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob+<>c__DisplayClass41_0+<<DownloadTextAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00061] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:594 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at QwikQuestion.Services.StorageDataService+<TestStorage>d__17.MoveNext () [0x00095] in C:\Users\alex\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\QwikQuestion\QwikQuestion\QwikQuestion\Services\StorageDataService.cs:56 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at QwikQuestion.ViewModels.ViewQuestionViewModel+<FetchQuestionTask>d__15.MoveNext () [0x00180] in C:\Users\alex\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\QwikQuestion\QwikQuestion\QwikQuestion\ViewModels\ViewQuestionViewModel.cs:55 
Request Information
RequestID:39730ffc-0001-00ed-45ed-69f892000000
RequestDate:Sun, 08 Jan 2017 20:27:34 GMT
StatusMessage:PartialContent
```

If I uncomment the UploadTextAsync then it also does nothing, and no Blob is created on Azure.

I'm probably committing some simple error, but I've tried every combination that I've found including CloudStorageAccount.Parse, CreateCloudBlobClient.  I think I'm on the right track because of the exceptions I'm getting from Azure if I give it a bad URL or Account.

Comment: I am guessing that the method in which the code above is written is async as well. Are you waiting (await) for that as well?

Comment: Are sure you're not swallowing an exception?

Comment: @guarav-mantri I added the function signature.  Yes, it is async.

Comment: @François Ok, I wrapped it up in a try/catch and I do get an exception after quite a while.  The exception is a StorageException NotImplemented with Status Code 206 (PartialContent).  I'll update the question with the Exception Output.

Comment: @GauravMantri Also, Azure throws an exception if the blob doesn't exist, but if it exists then it throws NotImplemented after a long timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the exception is due to a hashing function that is not implemented in Xamarin yet.  See issue for more details:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/387

The solution is to revert to Azure Storage 7.2.1 until fixed.